# different keys with same value in python

Tags: python

I am writing a simple game: "rock paper scissors". 
I assigned

1 to "paper",

2 to scissors,

3 to rock.

I wrote the function determining who wins. This function gets two values: the computer's choise and the user's choise.

```
def winner(computer, user) :
difference = computer - user 
dic = {
    [1,-2] : "computer" ,
    [-1,2] : "user",
    [0]: "draw"
    }
```

how can i give difference to dic and recive their value?

Comment: Dictionary keys cannot be of a mutable type, try using a tuple instead of a list. (Edit: VNM, just use 1: "computer", -2: "computer"

Comment: Consider this implementation: "if difference mod 3 == 2 then user, if difference mod 3 == 1 then computer else draw. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case you might consider to drop the `dict` entirely:

```
def winner(computer, user):
    difference = (computer - user) % 3
    if difference == 2:
        return "computer"
    elif difference == 1:
        return "user"
    return "draw"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple keys like that, as you've seen. You could, however, just enter several keys with the same value to the dictionary:

```
dic = {
    1 : "computer",
    -2 : "computer",
    -1 : "user",
    2 : "user",
    0: "draw"
}
```